# networkx says I have less nodes than I actually have

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a strange issue with NetworkX. 
Given the [DS-1 dataset](http://twiki.di.uniroma1.it/pub/Estrinfo/WebHome/datasetwebsocial2019.zip), my task is to create a graph per each year that is reported in the dataset. So far, no problem at all. For 2013, this is what I get

[image]

We could say... a little bit crowdy.
Now here's my strange issue. My assignment states that I should select, with some logic, the top k-nodes of every graph. So, since I have some graphs that have less than 5 nodes (and, per requirements, this k will be a value in [0,5,10,50,200]), I thought to exclude in the iteration those graphs whose len(G) is < k.
So, given a dictionary graphsPerYear (key: year - value: the graph)...

```
for x in graphsPerYear:
    G = graphsPerYear[x]
    if len(G) < k:
        print(G.nodes)
        print(G.number_of_nodes())
        print("Skipping year " + str(x) + " since it has " + str(len(G)) + " nodes which is less than the prompted k")
        continue
```

This outputs the following:

```
['linear matrix inequality', 'social inequality']
2
Skipping year 2013 since it has 2 nodes which is less than the prompted k
```

But the image tells the complete opposite. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Adding the creation of the graph

```
def createGraphPerYear(dataset, year):
    insertedWords = set()
    listaAnni = set(dataset['anno'].values)
    grafi = dict()
    for anno in listaAnni:
        datasetTemporale = dataset[dataset['anno'] == anno]
        G=nx.DiGraph()
        for index, row in datasetTemporale.iterrows():
            #Reminder: ogni row è formato da anno, keyword1, keyword2, dizionario utilizzatore keywords - numero volte
            #FASE 1: AGGIUNTA DEI DUE POSSIBILI NODI
            if row.keyword1 not in G:
                G.add_node(row.keyword1)
            if row.keyword2 not in G:
                G.add_node(row.keyword2)
            if not __areNodesConnected(G,row.keyword1, row.keyword2):
                G.add_edge(row.keyword1,row.keyword2)
        grafi[anno] = G
    return grafi

def __areNodesConnected(G, nodeToCheckOne,nodeToCheckTwo):
    return nodeToCheckOne in G.neighbors(nodeToCheckTwo)
```

Comment: A comment:  for a `DiGraph`, the command `G.add_edge(u,v)` will do nothing if there is already an edge from `u` to `v`.  Otherwise, if either of those nodes doesn't exist, it will first add the node and then create the edge.  So your `if` statements in the `for` loop can be removed, and `__areNodesConnected` is not needed.  [also `__areNodesConnected` is equivalent to `G.has_edge(nodeToCheckOne,nodeToCheckTwo)`].

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere in some other code you're not showing.  Can you draw the graph for `2013` and check that it looks like the plot you've shown and then immediately check `len(G)`?

Comment: @Joel so here's what I did: taken the for that iterates over graphsPerYear, right after the G iitialization, I put a nx.draw(G) plt.show() and, right after, a print(len(G)). The output is 170, which is cool to me (P.S.: Thanks for the comment!)

Answer (score 0):

When you add a node to networx it `hash`es it to determine uniqueness.
Any node with the same `hash` is determined to be identical.

```
By definition, a Graph is a collection of nodes (vertices) 
along with identified pairs of nodes (called edges, links, etc). 
In NetworkX, nodes can be any hashable object e.g., 
a text string, an image, an XML object, another Graph, 
a customized node object, etc.
```

Double check that the items are not the same string, or that their hashability is not equivalent for distinct nodes.

Comment: There 453 entries for 2013... Not saying that I don't want to check them all, but, imho, just a look at the image helps in seeing that there surely are different strings. Also: when creating the graph, I take good care in checking whether the keyword is already in it or not (if keyword not in G)

Comment: please post in your question when you `add_node` or `add_edge` and how that is done

Comment: Done, Nathan! :)

Comment: sto leggendo questi `tsv` ma non capisco il formatto, spiegami le colonne

Comment: So I have this dataset which represents how some keywords are used by some authors over time. Year: represents the year in which the row is referred to; keywordOne: is the first keyword used in some scientific papers; keywordTwo: same as before; the last column should represent a decorator of the edge that gets created between these two keywords

Comment: From the requirements: "Let V be the set of nodes that represents the different keywords used by articles in literature: e.g. machine learning, crawling, statistic inference, etc.  Let E be the set of edges which represent the relationship of two keywords being used by two different articles. Every edge  e={ki,kj}  is decorated with an ordered dictionary of authors. The dictionary of authors is organized as follows: key-value (a,n) pairs where a represents an author, whereas n is the number of times author a uses ki and kj in his/her articles."

Comment: what are the hashes? what is the last column of ds-2?

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, how do I retrieve it? I create a node from the two keywords that I'm seeing

Comment: look at the files

Comment: Ahhh you meant the decorators (last column in DS1)! Are you suggesting that it is giving me 2 nodes because they might all have the same dictionary as decorator of the edge?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195941/discussion-between-nathan-mccoy-and-gianmarco-f).